# InnoSetup: How to add line break into component description

Tags: inno-setup

I am trying to add a line break in the middle of my description for my components. But I can't seem to find the proper syntax for it.

```
[Components]
Name: Component A; Description: "This is component A:" + NewLine + "My component A has this stuff";
```

Comment: Perhaps the information in [Long descriptions on inno-setup components](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10867087) can help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Line breaks are not supported for [`[Components]`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=componentssection) section entries, but you can modify your component item descriptions from code (unfortunately, access to the property, which stores a description is indexed and there is no way to find an index by the component name).

This example shows how to modify the first component item's description (indexing is 0 based), and how to add a line break to it:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Components]
Name: "app"; Description: "Description is changed in [Code] section"
Name: "readme"; Description: "Readme File"

[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  WizardForm.ComponentsList.ItemCaption[0] :=
    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed id venenatis' + #13#10 +
    'erat, ac vehicula sapien. Etiam convallis ligula eros, in ullamcorper turpis' + #13#10 +
    'pulvinar sit amet.';
end;
```

Answer (score 9):

For the component description you can define a custom message where you can specify line breaks by the `%n` tags, e.g.:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[CustomMessages]
ComponentDescription=Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,%nconsectetur adipiscing elit.

[Components]
Name: "app"; Description: "{cm:ComponentDescription}"
Name: "readme"; Description: "Readme File"
```

Comment: @Jerry, `%n` in a `[Components]` entry `Description` won't produce line breaks. That's what you can do in `[CustomMessages]` section entries. But the principle of making line breaks through custom messages is much better than my idea.