# Inno Setup - Change a task description label's color and have a line break

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

```
[Components]
Name: "Slasher"; Description: "Dagon Slasher"; Types: Slasher Full
Name: "Frankenstein"; Description: "Dagon Frankenstein"; Types: Frankenstein Full

[Types]
Name: "Full"; Description: "Dagon Video Tools"
Name: "Slasher"; Description: "Dagon Slasher"
Name: "Frankenstein"; Description: "Dagon FrankenStein"

[Tasks]
Name: "Debug"; Description: "Debug. Warning: This will result in a non-functional ""Join in FrankenStein"" button in the Tools Menu."; Components: not Slasher
Name: "Vid"; Description: "Install Extra Codecs for Frankenstein"; Flags: unchecked; Components: not Slasher
```

I need `Warning: This will result in...` to be displayed on a new line and in red font. I found [TLama's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24671084/3993104) in [InnoSetup: How to add line break into component description](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24661916/850848) but it results in `List index out of bounds(0)` since, as you can see, the task is displayed conditionally in my script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try to update the `TasksList` in the `InitializeWizard`, you must get the exception as at that point the `TasksList` is not populated yet, no matter if the tasks are conditional or not.

The `TasksList` is populated only once you move to the "Select Additional Tasks" page.

So you need to update the task caption only in [`CurPageChanged(wpSelectTasks)`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurPageChanged). And test for [`not WizardIsComponentSelected('Slasher')`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_wizardiscomponentselected) (`IsComponentSelected` before Inno Setup 6.0.2) before you do so (see the comment in the code for details).

```pascal
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpSelectTasks then
  begin
    { This has to be kept in sync with the expression in "Components" parameter }
    { of the respective task. Though note that in your specific case the test }
    { is redundant as when "Slasher" is selected, you have no tasks, }
    { and the "Tasks" page is completely skipped, so you do not even get  here. }
    { Before Inno Setup 6.0.2, use IsComponentSelected. } 
    if not WizardIsComponentSelected('Slasher') then
    begin
      WizardForm.TasksList.ItemCaption[0] :=
        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed id' + #13#10 +
        'venenatis erat, ac vehicula sapien. Etiam convallis ligula eros,' + #13#10 +
        'in ullamcorper turpis pulvinar sit amet.';
    end;
  end;
end;
```

---

I'm pretty sure there's no way to change a color of one specific task. All you can do is to create a separate `TNewCheckListBox` for each group of tasks that should have a different color (and set the color using its `.Font.Color` property).

---

*If you want more details on this, you should ask a separate question. The line break and the color are two separate issues.*

*See also a similar question: [Disable controls based on components selection in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49242227/850848).*