# In Inno setup, how can I modify the component label?

Tags: inno-setup

How can I change the color or font type of component label?
I'd seen someone answered, but I can't find the thread recently.

[image]

Comment: I do not think it is possible (unless you use some 3rd party extension of Inno Setup). It's the same as here: [Inno Setup - Change a task description label's color and have a line break](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35817280/850848). My answer says: *"I'm pretty sure there's no way to change a color of one specific task. All you can do is to create a separate `TNewCheckListBox` for each group of tasks that should have a different color (and set the color using its `.Font.Color` property)."*

Comment: I see. Thanks for reply.