# Adding MouseOver descriptions for InnoSetup

Tags: inno-setup

I would like to be able to add mouse-over descriptions of components during install. I have seen some people mention it, but no one has offered a solution as to how this can be done. Does anyone have an example of this being done? Or a possible way to approach it?

Comment: See the comments to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10867087), which might help.