# Long Descriptions on my components with button "show descriptions"

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I would like to get the effect that appears in this installer:

[image]

I want him to be a button on the bottom of the "show description" when the button is enabled after click on the component, appears at the bottom of the description of the component. The image is not required.
Help! Much I care.

**My installation package components looks like this:**

[image]

Sorry for my English

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22866503/960757), [maybe this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10867087/960757) and I bet we could find many others...

Comment: I checked these subjects before and unfortunately it did not help, either because they show up when compiling with an application error code, or not got the effect I wanted.

Comment: Ok. But it doesn't change the fact they are duplicates. Besides, you should mention what have you tried in your question. It may save the time for people that will try to help you.

Comment: Pasting these scripts from the topics that you supplied when you compile the script - show error.
And as the error does not appear that the descriptions were not included in this place, and were not under my pendent components.