# Controlling system volume using trackbar in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

How can we control system volume using trackbar in Inno Setup?

With bass.dll or mediaplayer.dll we play music, but how to control system volume with trackbar to manage volume level?

And can forward and rewind option is available with those library?

Answer (score 2):

There's no trackbar control in Inno Setup.

But you can draw your own interactive volume bar using `TBitmapImage`:

```pascal
function GetCursorPos(var lpPoint: TPoint): BOOL;
  external 'GetCursorPos@user32.dll stdcall';
function ScreenToClient(hWnd: HWND; var lpPoint: TPoint): BOOL;
  external 'ScreenToClient@user32.dll stdcall';

procedure DrawVolume(Image: TBitmapImage; Volume: Integer);
var
  Canvas: TCanvas;
  Width: Integer;
begin
  Canvas := Image.Bitmap.Canvas;

  Canvas.Pen.Style := psClear;

  Width := Image.Bitmap.Width * Volume / 100

  Canvas.Brush.Color := clHighlight;
  Canvas.Rectangle(1, 1, Width, Image.Bitmap.Height);

  Canvas.Brush.Color := clBtnFace;
  Canvas.Rectangle(Width - 1, 1, Image.Bitmap.Width, Image.Bitmap.Height);

  Canvas.Pen.Style := psSolid;
  Canvas.Pen.Mode := pmCopy;
  Canvas.Pen.Color := clBlack;
  Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
  Canvas.Rectangle(1, 1, Image.Bitmap.Width, Image.Bitmap.Height);
end;

procedure VolumeBarImageClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  P: TPoint;
  Image: TBitmapImage;
  Volume: Integer;
begin
  { Calculate where in the bar did user click to }
  GetCursorPos(P);
  Image := TBitmapImage(Sender);
  ScreenToClient(Image.Parent.Handle, P);
  Volume := ((P.X - Image.Left) * 100 / Image.Width) + 1;

  { Update volume bar }
  DrawVolume(Image, Volume);

  { Replace this with your code that sets the volume }
  MsgBox(Format('Setting volume to %d%%', [Volume]), mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;  

procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  VolumeBarImage: TBitmapImage;
begin
  VolumeBarImage := TBitmapImage.Create(WizardForm);
  VolumeBarImage.Parent := WizardForm;
  VolumeBarImage.Left := ScaleX(10);
  VolumeBarImage.Top := WizardForm.ClientHeight - ScaleY(34);
  VolumeBarImage.Width := ScaleX(200);
  VolumeBarImage.Height := ScaleY(20);
  VolumeBarImage.BackColor := clWhite;
  VolumeBarImage.Bitmap.Width := VolumeBarImage.Width;
  VolumeBarImage.Bitmap.Height := VolumeBarImage.Height;
  VolumeBarImage.OnClick := @VolumeBarImageClick;

  { Replace with setting to actual initial volume }
  DrawVolume(VolumeBarImage, 100);
end;
```

[image: Volume bar]

---

The code is mostly from:

- [How do I change the color of my progress bar in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33630532/850848)
- [Inno Setup: OnHover event](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37347427/850848)