# Inno Setup - Change the color of the description of a particular component

Tags: inno-setup

I´m use this code: [Long descriptions on Inno Setup components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867087/long-descriptions-on-inno-setup-components/41649079?noredirect=1#comment70556564_41649079)

I'm trying to change the color of the description of the ¨Additional Files¨ only. How to change the color only of this? (when i move the mouse over ¨additional components¨ or ¨componentes adicionales¨).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `CompLabel.Font.Color`:

```pascal
if Index = 1 then
begin
  CompLabel.Font.Color := clRed;
end
  else
begin
  CompLabel.Font.Color := clWindowText;
end;
```

Comment: Is it possible to reduce the area over which, when positioning with the mouse, the color change of the description occurs? if i put the mouse pointer far from the words but in the same line, the color change occurs. I want that the change color occurs only if i put the mouse pointer over the words. (sorry for my bad english).

Comment: @NicoZ It may be possible. You would have to use `DrawText` WinAPI with `DT_CALCRECT` flag to calculate the text size. It would not be 100% even then.