# Identify, what Inno Setup tasks correspond to the items of TaskList (to show text on mouse over for certain tasks only)

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

So, I have these `comtools` tasks, which, as you can see, can have a different position in the tasks list, depending on which components were previously chosen. Moreover, they may not exist at all, if the user doesn't wish to install those components.
What I need is static text shown, but only when the cursor hovers over the  `comtools` tasks.

```
[Tasks]
Name: "acorig"; Description: "ac original"; GroupDescription: "Choose which version of ac to install:"; Flags: exclusive; Components: ac
Name: "acenh"; Description: "ac enhanced"; GroupDescription: "Choose which version of ac to install:"; Flags: exclusive unchecked; Components: ac
Name: "ac2comtools"; Description: "ac2"; GroupDescription: "Also install community-made tools (unsupported) for:"; Flags: unchecked; Components: ac2
Name: "bccomtools"; Description: "bc"; GroupDescription: "Also install community-made tools (unsupported) for:"; Flags: unchecked; Components: bc
Name: "bc2comtools"; Description: "bc2"; GroupDescription: "Also install community-made tools (unsupported) for:"; Flags: unchecked; Components: bc
Name: "bc3comtools"; Description: "bc3"; GroupDescription: "Also install community-made tools (unsupported) for:"; Flags: unchecked; Components: bc3
Name: "bc4comtools"; Description: "bc4"; GroupDescription: "Also install community-made tools (unsupported) for:"; Flags: unchecked; Components: bc4
```

Yes, I did see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37796528/3993104, but that ties the description to index, which is not practical here. Also, that code shows description for all items in `TasksList`.

---

Edit: So, the only change I made to the code after Martin's answer (aside from moving everything over to the tasks page) was adding Martin's function, and editing `HoverComponentChanged` like this:

```pascal
procedure HoverComponentChanged(Index: Integer);
var 
  Description: string;
begin
  case Index of
    -1: Description := '';
    LookupTask('ac2comtools'): Description := 'This is the description of AC2';
    LookupTask('bccomtools'): Description := 'This is the description of BC';
    LookupTask('bc2comtools'): Description := 'This is the description of BC2';
    LookupTask('bc3comtools'): Description := 'This is the description of BC3';
  else
    Description := '';
  end;
  TaskLabel.Caption := Description;
end;
```

`-1` is a failsafe, since, when one of the components in deselected, then the index for the corresponding task is `-1`, which means you will see the description for the first deselected component in this list, when your cursor is outside of `TasksList`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's really no straightforward way to identify, what tasks correspond to the items of `TaskList`.

---

Quick and dirty way is to use item description.

In this case, it's better to define the description using a [custom message](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=custommessagessection), so that you can refer to it in the code. And it's a must anyway, if your installer is localized.

```
[CustomMessages]
AC2ComTools=ac2

[Tasks]
Name: "ac2comtools"; Description: {cm:AC2ComTools}
```

```pascal
[Code]

function LookupTask(TaskCustomMessage: string): Integer;
var
  Description: string;
begin
  Description := CustomMessage(TaskCustomMessage);
  Result := WizardForm.TasksList.Items.IndexOf(Description);
  Log(Format('Index of "%s" task is %d', [Description, Result]));
end;
```

Use it like:

```pascal
AC2ComToolsIndex := LookupTask('ac2comtools');
```

---

Another way is to reproduce the logic of Inno Setup for deciding, what tasks to show.

Use [`WizardIsComponentSelected` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_wizardiscomponentselected) (`IsComponentSelected` before Inno Setup 6.0.2).

```pascal
// Before Inno Setup 6.0.2, use IsComponentSelected.
if WizardIsComponentSelected('ac2') then
begin
  if WizardIsComponentSelected('ac') then AC2ComToolsIndex := 4
    else AC2ComToolsIndex := 1;
end
  else AC2ComToolsIndex := -1;
```

---

If you want to create a full mapping from task name to `TaskList` item index automatically, you can do something like this each time the task list changes, i.e. on call to [`CurPageChanged(wpSelectTasks)`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurPageChanged):

- Remember current task state
- Check all task checkboxes
- Read [`WizardSelectedTasks(False)`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_wizardselectedtasks) to get names of all tasks
- Generate the mapping
- Restore previous task state.

This is relatively easy, when there are only checkboxes, not radio buttons (i.e. no task with `exclusive` flag).

```pascal
var
  Tasks: TStringList;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
var
  TasksChecked: array of Boolean;
  I: Integer;
begin
  if CurPageID = wpSelectTasks then
  begin
    SetArrayLength(TasksChecked, WizardForm.TasksList.Items.Count);
    // Remember current task state + Check all task checkboxes
    for I := 0 to WizardForm.TasksList.Items.Count - 1 do
    begin
      TasksChecked[I] := WizardForm.TasksList.Checked[I];
      WizardForm.TasksList.Checked[I] := True;
    end;
    Tasks := TStringList.Create;
    Tasks.CommaText := WizardSelectedTasks(False);  
    for I := 0 to WizardForm.TasksList.Items.Count - 1 do
    begin
      // Insert blank items for "group descriptions"
      if WizardForm.TasksList.ItemObject[I] = nil then
        Tasks.Insert(I, '');
      // Restore previous task state
      WizardForm.TasksList.Checked[I] := TasksChecked[I];
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Now you can use the `Tasks` to lookup corresponding task index:

```pascal
AC2ComToolsIndex := Tasks.IndexOf('ac2comtools');
```

Though as you have `exclusive` tasks, you would need much more complicated code.