# How can I move around and program individual controls on the CreateInputOptionPage in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

How can I move around and program individual radio buttons on my `CreateInputOptionPage` page? 
For example, I want to put some text under each of my radio buttons and be able to move them around as if they were created as custom `TNewRadioButton` objects.
I've created a page using the `CreateInputOptionPage` like this:

```pascal
TestPage := CreateInputOptionPage(wpWelcome, 'CAPTION', 'DESCRIPTION', 'SUBCAPTION', True, False);
TestPage.Add('RADIO1');
TestPage.Add('RADIO2');
TestPage.CheckListBox.Left := 0;
```

Comment: While you can move around individual *controls*, you cannot move individual radio buttons, as they are not separate *controls*. Sorry, if I my comment to you previous question gave you wrong assumptions. – You might be able to use `MinItemHeight` to add some space between the buttons, where you might place your description. But I'm not sure it will work correctly. – You also might be able to use a solution like this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10867087/850848

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Looks like it is not possible to have radio buttons and checkboxes on the same page, right?

Comment: It is possible.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl By using `AddEx` method?

Comment: I do not know what are you trying to achieve. Please post a new question with details.